# How to escape pipe character in `:make`, `:grep` and friends

Tags: command-line, escape, makeprg

I'm trying to use `:grep` to search for one of several words. Since grep accepts regular expressions, I figured I could just use the pipe character `|` to build a single expression for both words:

```
:grep -E 'foo|baz' *.c
```

Vim interprets the `|` as a separator between two commands. `:help :bar` suggests that I could escape it as `\|`, but that doesn't work, either. It seems that the `:grep` command does not handle backspaces and quotes.

`:help map-bar` also offers the suggestion to use `^V|`, which actually escapes the pipe character, but now the `^V` is also in my pattern.

Right now, the only workaround I've found is using environment variables:

```
:let $BAR = '|' | grep -E 'foo'$BAR'baz' *.c
```

But this is quite crazy in my opinion. Is there really no better way?

Comment: Just to be sure: have you read `:h magic` or http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html ?

Comment: @lsrdg I think that option does not matter because the regexp is parsed by an external command.

Comment: sorry, my bad. It just worked for me with `'foo\\|baz'`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm confused. This really did not work when I tried it an hour ago. Now it does...

Comment: With grep, right? I haven't tried with make. Anyway, sounds like good news. And sorry for my first useless comment. (:

Comment: @lsrdg Yes, with grep. Sorry for the useless question and thanks for making me try again ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated on the question, `:h map-bar` suggests escaping the pipe with with `\|`.
However, grep apparently understands that as a literal bar, thus the backslash needs to be escaped as well. This should work for grep:

`:grep -E 'foo\\|baz' *.c`

NOTE: there's no need to escape the backslash with **vimgrep** (`:h :vimgrep`). The following seems to give the same results here:

`:vimgrep 'foo\|baz' *.c`