# How to escape a pipe (|) in my vimrc

Tags: vimrc, escape, original-vim

> I've seen
>
> - [How to escape pipe character in `:make`, `:grep` and friends](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/how-to-escape-pipe-character-in-make-grep-and-friends)
> - [How to escape pipe (|) in mapped substitution?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29165/how-to-escape-pipe-in-mapped-substitution)
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596150/use-to-diplay-tabs-in-vim
>
> But none of them solved my problem

I'm trying to set my listchars in my vimrc like this:

```
set listchars=tab:|
```

But I got the error: `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:`

I tried escaping the pipe as `\|` and `^V|` and `\\|` and a bunch of variations, but nothing worked.

The weird thing is that I can do other stuff (like `nnoremap \|`) with no problems at all. The only problem is for `listchars`.

Comment: `tab` requires either 2 or 3 letters, not only a single letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read `:h 'lcs'`: "Two or three characters to be used to show a tab". First, the first one. Then the second one repeated as many times as needed.

```
set lcs=tab:\|\|
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. What I want to know is how to escape a `|`. `\|` didn't work for me.

Comment: @Siddharth I'm pretty sure you didn't understand my answer. `\|` works for me and everyone else.